# ¿Ha publicado la RAE un diccionario de sinónimos?

Tags: sinónimos, rae, recursos, antónimos

La RAE mantiene/contribuye a varios diccionarios:

- Diccionario de la lengua española
- Diccionario del español jurídico
- Diccionario de americanismos
- Diccionario panhispánico de dudas

¿Ha publicado alguna vez la RAE un diccionario de sinónimos o antónimos?

Answer (score 2):

Parece ser que no.

En la sección [Diccionarios](https://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios) de la web de la RAE aparece todo un listado de las obras que ha ido elaborando con el tiempo. Como comentan allí:

> La corporación, creada en 1713 por el marqués de Villena, se fijó como tarea prioritaria la elaboración de un diccionario de la lengua castellana, «el más copioso que pudiera hacerse». Tras alcanzar el objetivo en 1726, año de publicación del primero de los seis tomos del Diccionario de autoridades, los propósitos fundacionales han continuado hasta hoy ininterrumpidamente (...)
>
> De esta obra principal han derivado otros diccionarios, concebidos para responder a las necesidades de grupos de usuarios más delimitados, como el Diccionario esencial de la lengua española y el Diccionario del estudiante (...)

Todos los que mencionan aparecen listados a continuación, por lo que la sensación es que esta lista es exhaustiva y cubre todos los diccionarios que ha hecho la RAE a lo largo de su (larga) historia:

- [Diccionario de la lengua española](http://dle.rae.es/)
- [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](https://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/dpd)
- [Diccionario del español jurídico](http://dej.rae.es/)
- [Nuevo diccionario histórico](https://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/nuevo-diccionario-historico)
- [Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/)
- [Diccionarios anteriores (1726-2006)](https://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-2006)

  - Diccionario de autoridades
  - Nuevo tesoro lexicográfico
  - Mapa de diccionarios
  - Diccionario histórico (1933-1936)
  - Diccionario histórico (1960-1996)
  - Diccionario de la lengua española (2001)
  - Diccionario esencial (2006)